# Change ToC to \section instead of \chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, fontsize, report

I'm using the report class, and because of this, my table of contents is also displayed as a chapter (i.e. using a chapter heading for "Contents"). This is overly large, and *just* causes my ToC to wrap to a new page.

Instead, I would like to use the regular heading from `\section`. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the definition of \tableofcontents from report.cls and change `chapter` to `section`, see the following example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \section*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I ended up doing something similar by using `{\let\chapter\section\tableofcontents}`, effectively doing it the other way around: in that case, chapter _becomes_ section in this scope.

Comment: Using `{\let\chapter\section\tableofcontents}` doesn't work for me. I use the scrreprt class.